# Correct order of performing imputation and variable selection

Tags: feature-selection, data-imputation, regression-strategies, data-preprocessing

This is a general question about performing data analysis.
I have a data set with ~1000 sample size and 200 features. Some of features have more than 50% missing or even higher. The missing pattern is unclear to me. I plan to do regression.
Any one can provide some reference where should I start and what is the correct procedure to do?
Suppose the variables needs no transformation.

What might be done before regression include:

A. looking at those with very high missing rate(>90% maybe?) and discard them

B. impute the remaining variables

C. perform variable selection

Is it reasonable to do step A? If yes, how to determine the cut-off rate?
Between imputation and variable selectin, which should be done first?